# How to replace selected text with stored text with JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have a textarea and I select some text (with my cursor):

> Text
>
> **Text** <-- selected text
>
> Text

And lets say I have a variable called `storedText`. How do I got about to replace the selected text with the content of `storedText`?

> Text
>
> **Stored Text** <-- selected text
>
> Text